# Two language on android

Tags: languages

I'm french, my system is in french.
I would like to be able to type english words without being bothered by the autocorrection.

How can i proceed ?

Edit: Free solutions please

Comment: Get a keyboard with dual language support? I know SwiftKey does it (there's a month free trial on the Play Store).

Comment: +1 for SwiftKey (costs 3 eur). I use it with Dutch and English and it works like a charm. I can even mix Dutch and English in the same text input (I tend to do that a lot :)

Comment: See the accepted answer, you can use multiple languages with android keybord for free.

Comment: @Imorin last time I checked it was not possible to type in two languages at the same time. SwiftKey does allow this and there is no need to switch languages while typing.

Comment: The solution given in the accepted answer allow to type in english on a french system. It won't correct english words but they will be allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember well:

In the language and input settings click the settings icon next Google Keyboard.

You can then change the input languages settings and select multiple languages.

Finally go the advanced settings there should be a way to enable a key that allows you to easily switch your input method when typing (from memory it was by holding the space bar)

Bon courage!

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem, where I often type in Italian using many English words or even expressions. If you can't find a keyboard with support for two separate languages (I know the Xperia default keyboard does, for example), I strongly suggest you to try SwiftKey. Along with many wonderful features, it is also able to recognize up to three languages at a time (e.g. you can start typing in French, and then type a word in English: SwiftKey will recognize you're now using English, and apply the English autocorrect and suggestions) - just install the appropriate language packs (in your case, French, English (GB) and English (US)).
SwiftKey has a free trial that lasts 1 month, but some googling is enough to find out how to bypass the limit.

Comment: Why not just pay the 3 euro? If you like the product (like I do) you should reward the developers.

Answer (score 0):

If auto-correct is the problem, I'd just turn it off. Then you can type whatever you want without the system trying to over-ride your decisions. It does mean that you'll have to take responsibility for any spelling mistakes, but it also means no more having your words twisted by a matching algorithm.

Comment: Oh thinking that way i guess i should just stop using my phone.